# How to make 3D racing game with XNA?

Tags: xna-4.0

I would like to know how to make an 3D racing game with xna. I never used it but I want to learn starting with that kind of game.

Does anyone has any ideas where I can find any tutorials to start with? 
Or what shall I do?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent book on XNA called [Professional XNA Programming : Building Games for Xbox 360 and Windows with XNA Game Studio](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-XNA-Programming-Building-Games-for-Xbox-360-and-Windows-with-XNA-Game-Studio-2-0-2nd-Edition.productCd-0470261285.html). It doesn't explain every little detail, so if you want to build your way up there are a couple of books on XNA 4.0. Check out the listing at PacktPub http://www.packtpub.com/books/all?keys=xna. If you find other books on Game Programming, they will also help you.